# ckeditor textarea customization with jquery drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am doing a project in ckeditor.i want to add divs to the textarea of ckeditor and it should be draggable and dropable.I have already added a div and style to div.But jquery click event is not working on the div inside text area.The code i have used is below and it works on focus event.
Thanks in advance

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'content' );
    CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, '/ckfinder/' ) ;    

    var ckeditor = CKEDITOR.instances['content'];
    ckeditor.on('focus', fnHandler);

});

function fnHandler(){
    alert("Working");
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<textarea class="ckeditor" name="content" id="content" cols="20" rows="40">

<div id="makeMeDraggable"> </div>
</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Test it on their demo page first, to see if what you want to do works there!. You may have to take it up with the ckeditor developers, and ensure you have the latest version of it installed, as well as the latest libraries that it relies on it, like jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test it on their demo page first, to see if what you want to do works there!.

http://ckeditor.com/demo

You may have to take it up with the ckeditor developers, and ensure you have the latest version of it installed, as well as the latest libraries that it relies on it, like jQuery.

If it still does not work, then you may have to customize the Javascript libraries, or find another plugin that works, like ones they use in DotNetnuke or any other mainstream CMS system.